# validating all the html rows when the form is submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I am working on the html table where user can enter the details and click on submit button to submit the data to the backend.
I have 3 mandatory columns (Spring,Role,Project) which are mandatory to enter by the user before sending to the backend when clicked on submit button.
If user enters the data in first two rows and click on submit button, i want to validate if user has entered data in mandatory fields Sprint,Role and Project for each row and 
if user has missed to enter data in mandatory fields then i want to show error message near that row saying "Please enter the mandatory fields". I am confused as how to show error message for each row if user has not entered data in the 
madatory fields when user click on submit button after entering data in first 3 rows. Any inputs would be helpful.
I have total of 6 rows where user can enter details in all or few of them and click on submit button. Only i need to validate the rows and show error message near each row which has missing data in the mandatory fields.

Demo link : https://plnkr.co/edit/QbiuE8jOIwd2t40akBwe?p=preview

Sample html code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        function submitData(){
          alert("submit");
          
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<table id="productTable" border="1">

    <tr>
        <th>SID</th>
        <th>Sprint <span style="color:red;">*</span></th>
        <th>Role<span style="color:red;">*</span></th>
        <th>Comments</th>
        <th>Project<span style="color:red;">*</span></th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="sid" value=""></td>
        <td>
            <select class="sprint" >
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="">121.1</option>
                <option value="">121.2</option>
                <option value="">121.3</option>
                <option value="">122.1</option>
                <option value="">122.2</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="role" value="">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="Comments" value="">
        </td>
        <td>
            <select class="project" >
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="">ProA</option>
                <option value="">ProB</option>
                <option value="">ProC</option>
                <option value="">ProD</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="sid" value=""></td>
        <td>
            <select class="sprint" >
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="">121.1</option>
                <option value="">121.2</option>
                <option value="">121.3</option>
                <option value="">122.1</option>
                <option value="">122.2</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="role" value="">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="Comments" value="">
        </td>
        <td>
            <select class="project" >
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="">ProA</option>
                <option value="">ProB</option>
                <option value="">ProC</option>
                <option value="">ProD</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="sid" value=""></td>
        <td>
            <select class="sprint" >
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="">121.1</option>
                <option value="">121.2</option>
                <option value="">121.3</option>
                <option value="">122.1</option>
                <option value="">122.2</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="role" value="">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="Comments" value="">
        </td>
        <td>
            <select class="project" >
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="">ProA</option>
                <option value="">ProB</option>
                <option value="">ProC</option>
                <option value="">ProD</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="sid" value=""></td>
        <td>
            <select class="sprint" >
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="">121.1</option>
                <option value="">121.2</option>
                <option value="">121.3</option>
                <option value="">122.1</option>
                <option value="">122.2</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="role" value="">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="Comments" value="">
        </td>
        <td>
            <select class="project" >
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="">ProA</option>
                <option value="">ProB</option>
                <option value="">ProC</option>
                <option value="">ProD</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="sid" value=""></td>
        <td>
            <select class="sprint" >
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="">121.1</option>
                <option value="">121.2</option>
                <option value="">121.3</option>
                <option value="">122.1</option>
                <option value="">122.2</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="role" value="">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="Comments" value="">
        </td>
        <td>
            <select class="project" >
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="">ProA</option>
                <option value="">ProB</option>
                <option value="">ProC</option>
                <option value="">ProD</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="sid" value=""></td>
        <td>
            <select class="sprint" >
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="">121.1</option>
                <option value="">121.2</option>
                <option value="">121.3</option>
                <option value="">122.1</option>
                <option value="">122.2</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="role" value="">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="Comments" value="">
        </td>
        <td>
            <select class="project" >
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="">ProA</option>
                <option value="">ProB</option>
                <option value="">ProC</option>
                <option value="">ProD</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>       

</table> <br>
<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="submitData()">
```

Comment: put your code inside a <form> and use jquery.validate

Answer (score 1):

check if all data entered or not then the rest data is entered partially

```
if (sprint && role && project) {.....}
else if (!sprint && !role && !project) {} // do nothing
else {....}
```

Demo:

```js
function submitData() {
  var dataPassed = false,
    dataCount = 0,
    hasEnteredData = false;
  $('#productTable tr:not(:first)').each(function(index) {

    var sprint = $(this).find('.sprint :selected').text(),
      role = $(this).find('input[name="role"]').val(),
      project = $(this).find('.project :selected').text();
    if (sprint && role && project) {
      dataPassed = true
      dataCount++;
    }
    else if (!sprint && !role && !project) {
      // all empty, skip
    }
    else {
      alert('Required data missing in row: ' +
        (index + 1) + '\nfill: Sprint, Role, Project')
      dataPassed = false;
      hasEnteredData = true;
      return false;
    }
  })

  if (dataPassed) {
    alert('Success, Data count: ' +
      dataCount + ' rows, submit?');
    // do submit
  }
  else if (!hasEnteredData) {
    alert('No data entered')
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="productTable" border="1">

    <tr>
      <th>SID</th>
      <th>Sprint <span style="color:red;">*</span></th>
      <th>Role<span style="color:red;">*</span></th>
      <th>Comments</th>
      <th>Project<span style="color:red;">*</span></th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="sid" value="">
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="sprint">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="">121.1</option>
          <option value="">121.2</option>
          <option value="">121.3</option>
          <option value="">122.1</option>
          <option value="">122.2</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="role" value="">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="Comments" value="">
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="project">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="">ProA</option>
          <option value="">ProB</option>
          <option value="">ProC</option>
          <option value="">ProD</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="sid" value="">
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="sprint">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="">121.1</option>
          <option value="">121.2</option>
          <option value="">121.3</option>
          <option value="">122.1</option>
          <option value="">122.2</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="role" value="">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="Comments" value="">
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="project">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="">ProA</option>
          <option value="">ProB</option>
          <option value="">ProC</option>
          <option value="">ProD</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="sid" value="">
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="sprint">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="">121.1</option>
          <option value="">121.2</option>
          <option value="">121.3</option>
          <option value="">122.1</option>
          <option value="">122.2</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="role" value="">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="Comments" value="">
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="project">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="">ProA</option>
          <option value="">ProB</option>
          <option value="">ProC</option>
          <option value="">ProD</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="submitData()">
```

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. Instead of showing an alert message I want to display an error message near each row of the missing required fields on the right hand side of the table with red color font. Is it possible?

Comment: it just example. it possible but need more work, try find js form library.